# Questions about density of $\left\{\ \left( k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)^n \right\}$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: open-problem, fractional-part

Here, $\{ x \}$ denotes the fractional part of $x.$

> Are there any known positive integers $k$ for which the set $\left\{\ \left\{
> \left( k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)^n \right\}: n\in\mathbb{N}\ \right\} $ is
> known to be dense in $[0,1]$ ?

I know this is an open problem for $k=1,$ so suspect it might also be an open problem for all other integers $k,$ which then leads to the following question:

> If the answer to the first question is no, then is the set $\left\{\ \left\{ \left( k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)^n
> \right\}: n,k\in\mathbb{N}\ \right\} $ known to be dense in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I don't think the second question should be too hard. Can't you get all (dyadic) rationals with denominator $2^n$ by ranging $k$, for any fixed $n$?

Comment: @mathworker21 If $n=2,$ then $\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \equiv \frac{1}{4} \mod 1.$ So you don't get $\frac{3}{4}$ there. Or maybe I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: You didn't misunderstand, was just spitballing. I'll try $n=3,4$ later... Maybe odd $n$ are fine?

Comment: Yea, so my above comment does work. Here's mathematica code giving experimental evidence s = {};
n = 1;
While[n < 20, k = 1; 
 While[k < 20, x = FractionalPart[(k + 1/2)^n]; 
  If[MemberQ[s, x], Nothing, AppendTo[s, x]]; k++]; n++]
ListPlot[Sort[s]]

Answer (score 4):

For the second question the answer is yes. Note that
$$(k + 0.5)^n = 2^{-n} + nk2^{-n+1} + \sum_{j = 2}^{n} \binom{n}{j}k^j 2^{-n+j}.$$
Thus, if we take $n = 2m$, $k = 2^{m - 1} t$ for integer $t$, then for any $j \geq 2$, the number $\binom{n}{j}k^j 2^{-n+j}$ is an integer. So we conclude that
$$\{(k + 0.5)^n\} = \{2^{-2m} + mt2^{-m+1}\}.$$
In particular, as $t$ travels from $0$ to $2^{m - 1} / m$, the RHS comes within $m2^{-m+1}$ of any number in $[0,1]$. Taking $m \to \infty$ gives the desired density.